# Does bazel theoretically allow http requests inside bazel build rules?

Tags: bazel, starlark

Is there any possibility to write http requests in starlark `build` rule or via some executable invoked by `ctx.actions.run` ?

I know it can be done with bazel `test` (inside test runners), but can it be done in build phase? I know this goes against network sandboxing (but lets say we turn it off)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set [`execution_requirements`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/actions.html#run.execution_requirements) to include [`requires-network`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/common-definitions.html#common.tags).

Some notes:

- The network requests are only within actions, they can't be run from Starlark itself
- Bazel won't know to rerun actions that depend on network requests if the remote information has changed. There would need to be a way to make an action always run, which hasn't been decided on: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3041